# Custom toolbar disappears with call to imshow

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to create a simple GUI script in Matlab to show a series of images, with a toolbar to provide basic functionality related to the current image. But I have noticed that calling "imshow" causes the custom toolbar in the figure window to disappear. Any idea how to change the behavior so that the toolbar persists? Or is unaffected by the "imshow" call?

The relevant code is:

```matlab
% create viewer window
win_viewer = figure('Visible', 'on', 'Name', 'Sample', ...
    'Position', [0 0 200 200], 'NumberTitle', 'off', 'Toolbar', ...
    'none', 'MenuBar', 'none', 'Resize', 'off', 'Color', ...
    [0 0 0]);

gui_toolbar = uitoolbar('Parent', win_viewer);

% add save button
icons = load('icons.mat');
gui_save = uipushtool('Parent', gui_toolbar, 'CData', icons.disk{1}, ...
    'ClickedCallback', {@cb_saveImage}, 'TooltipString', ...
    'Save Movie');

% create axes
win_axes = axes('Parent', win_viewer);
axis off;

% this is called multiple times
imshow(im, 'Parent', win_axes, 'Border', 'tight');
imshow(im, 'Parent', win_axes, 'Border', 'tight');
```

Until the "imshow" call, the toolbar appears and works as expected. But but once the image is shown, the toolbar disappears.

**Edit:** I just played with it a bit, and it is only the subsequent calls to "imshow" that cause the toolbar a bit. I update the code to have to two calls to emphasize this.

Comment: It stays on my system (R2014b), but perhaps you can try to check the toolbar handle `gui_toolbar.isvalid` to see if it's just not visible, in which case you can turn it back on.

Comment: Also make sure that the 'WindowStyle' property of the figure is NOT set to 'modal': check the 'tips' section here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitoolbar.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I too am using R2014b, but realized that it is only the second imshow call that causes the toolbar to disappear (I clarified that in my question). The "isvalid" becomes false on the subsequent "imshow" call, and accessing other toolbar properties results in an "deleted object" error. The window is not modal though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting toolbar's `HandleVisibility` property to `off` before using **imshow**.